# With drf-yasg, how can i show multiple openapi schemes?

Tags: python, django, drf-yasg

Used: `Django 2.2, drf-yasg 1.17.1, python 3.9`

How can I show with drf-yasg multiple openapi schemes?

API returning different responses, depending on the request.

Basic response:

[image: Basic response]

Is it possible in drf-yasg to show responses like this?

[image: Expected Result]

In the yaml file, this is implemented using `oneOf`.

Code example:

```
responses:
        '200':
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                properties:
                  count:
                    type: integer
                  next:
                    type: string
                  previous:
                    type: string
                  results:
                      oneOf:
                        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/BaseStocks'
                        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Apteka36.6Stocks'
                        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/FarmiyaStocks'
                        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/MailruStocks'
                        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/NeofarmStocks'
                        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/YandexStock'
                        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/UtekaStocks'
```

Is it possible to repeat such a construction with drf-yasg?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible.

`oneOf` - has been added to OpenAPI 3.0, drf-yasg only supports [OpenAPI 2.0](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/readme.html#openapi-3-0-note)